# How to filter array that has item with the same name but different value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array that has items in it.

I make this array through collecting form data with this function:

```
    getFormdata : function(form) {
        var formdata = $(form)
            .serializeArray()
            .filter(function (item) {
                return item.name != "__RequestVerificationToken"
            });

        return formdata;
    }
```

When I have a checkbox in the form and when it is checked I get two items in the array where one has the value

> true

and the other has

> false

I am using jquery filter functon to filter the array but I can't figure out how I can discared the item that has the value

> false

the undesiered result of the array:

[image]

my attempt:

```
    getFormdata : function(form) {
        var formdata = $(form)
            .serializeArray()
            .filter(function (item) {
                return item.name != "__RequestVerificationToken" && (item.name == "IsActive" && item.value != "false");
            });

        return formdata;
    }
```

but this filters out all elements and not just the one I want removed.

How do I do this?

EDIT:

Item nr 2 should only be removed if there are two items with the same name.
If i have ONLY one item with the name "IsActive" then nr 2 should not be removed

Comment: Could you give us an exemple of input array and axpected result

Comment: I have, can't you see the image? the desiered result is basicly the same but without item nr 2

Comment: so you have 2 properties name and value but what do you want as a result?  perhaps an other image

Comment: Side note, with your conditional as you have it, you really don't need the first name check.  The second name == check if true would also assert that the first one is true.

Comment: Try to describe the condition in a single sentence (and then convert it to code): *"Keep an item if ...*" . I believe you want `item.name === 'isActive' ? item.value !== 'false' : item.name !== '__RequestVerificationToken'` .

Comment: @Nina Scholz gave me what I was looking for. Ill try to explain however since I dont agree with the vote down. If there are two instances of the property "IsActive" and one of them has the value = "false" then I want the item with the value "false" filtered out

Comment: please edit your question to what you really want. please add some examples.

Comment: @Ra3IDeN, Bu default, _JavaScript_ Arrays don't have names but indexes. But since Arrays are also of Type Object, they too can receive _Named Properties_ as any other JS object would, and is able to. So to be able to remove duplicate entries with the same name property _natively_, without even bothering to filter them in a separate process - you should be using a true object Object instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If two "IsActive" exists, remove the false one.  Otherwise, leave it alone.
Added the removal of the validation token.
Moved the check for value != "false" before the second filter to possibly short circuit the conditional and gain performance.

```js
var test = [
  { name: "__RequestVerificationToken", value: "whatever" },
  { name: "IsActive", value: "true" },
  { name: "updateRate", value: "sss" },
  { name: "IsActive", value: "false" },
  { name: "somethingElse", value: "weee" }
];

console.log(test.filter(function(element, index, array){
  return  element.name != "__RequestVerificationToken" && (
            element.value != "false"
            || array.filter(function(element2){
              return element2.name == element.name
            }).length < 2
          );
}));

var test = [
  { name: "__RequestVerificationToken", value: "whatever" },
  { name: "updateRate", value: "sss" },
  { name: "IsActive", value: "false" },
  { name: "somethingElse", value: "weee" }
];

console.log(test.filter(function(element, index, array){
  return  element.name != "__RequestVerificationToken" && (
            element.value != "false"
            || array.filter(function(element2){
              return element2.name == element.name
            }).length < 2
          );
}));
```

Comment: you are right on the money, I was a bit fast and accepted the other answer which was a good attempt and the question did not include all info when @Nina Scholz posted her answer

Answer (score 0):

You could check first if an active item exist and use it as later check for filtering.

```js
function filter(array) {
    var isActive = array.some(function (item) {
            return item.name === "IsActive" && item.value === "true";
        });
    return array.filter(function (item) {
        return (
            item.name !== "__RequestVerificationToken" && item.name !== "IsActive" ||
            item.name === "IsActive" && (item.value === "true" || !isActive)
        );
    });
}

var data0 = [{ name: 'IsActive', value: 'true' }, { name: 'IsActive', value: 'false' }, { name: 'Name', value: 'sss' }, { name: 'UpdateRate', value: '121212' }, { name: '__RequestVerificationToken', value: 'true' }, { name: '__RequestVerificationToken', value: 'false' }],
    data1 = [{ name: 'IsActive', value: 'false' }, { name: 'Name', value: 'sss' }, { name: 'UpdateRate', value: '121212' }, { name: '__RequestVerificationToken', value: 'true' }, { name: '__RequestVerificationToken', value: 'false' }];

console.log(filter(data0));
console.log(filter(data1));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This did the trick. I must say when reading I thought it cant be right since you exclude the property "IsActive" but the second line came in to play. Nice one!

Comment: yes, exclude in the first check and include in the second.

Comment: This looks flawed.  The original post said to include IsActive as false if it was the only IsActive in the list.  This logic will remove it if it is false and is the only one.

Comment: @Taplar you are correct but my lack of exmplaining was the cause that Nina missed it. Should not be down voted